# Is there a shorthand for document.write in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

in .NET you have `<%=` or `<%:` in PHP it's `echo`, but does JavaScript have a shorthand for `document.write()`?

Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it doesn't.

You can always:

```
function x (foo) { document.write(foo); } 
/* Where x is an unhelpfully short and uninformative function name */
```

Generally speaking, document.write should be avoided anyway. It is only useful during initial document generation and does nothing to handle special characters.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, more than one.

But "**with**" is considered **harmful** because if you make mistake to call a property that is not set you can change the value of another property or create a new global variable with that property ( more info [here](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/04/11/with-statement-considered-harmful/) )

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/wHK7t/)

```
var d = document;
d.write('text');

with (document){
    write('text');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The innerHTML property is a useful one for HTML elements. You can use that rather than document.write.

```
<p id="paragraph1"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
var elem = document.getElementById("paragraph1");
elem.innerHTML = "This is my paragraph.";
</script>
```

That allows you to have a lot more control over what you are outputting to the page. You can make that a bit easier to digest by wrapping it in a function - once you've declared the function once, you can reuse it as many times as you like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function wr(a,b) {
var elem = document.getElementById(a);
elem.innerHTML = b;
}
</script>
```

Very simple example, should be refined etc.